# Correct modeling historical records in a database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, scala, orm

In my applications I have a set of object which stay alive during the whole application lifecycle and I need to create an historical database of them.

These objects are instances of a hierarchy of Java / Scala classes annotated with Hibernate annotations, which I use in my application to load them at startup. Luckily all the classes already contain a timestamp, which means that I do not need to change the object model to be able to create historical records.

What is the most suitable approach:

1. Use Hibernate without annotations and providing external xml mappings, which are the same as the one of annotations besides the primary key ( which is now a composite key consisting of the previous primary key + the timestamp)
2. Use other classes for historical records ( this sounds very complicated, as I do have a hierarchy of classes and not a single class, and I would have to subclass my HistoricalRecordClass for every type of record, as I want to build it back). Still use Hibernate
3. Use a completely different approach (Please not I do not like ORMS, it is just a matter of convience)

Some considerations:

The goal of storing historical records is that the user, through a single GUI, might access both the real-time values of certain data or the historical value, just by specifying a date.

Answer (score 1):

How do you intend to use the historical records? The easiest solution would be to serialize them as JSON and log them to a file.

I've never combined hibernate xml mappings in conjunction with hibernate annotations, but if it worked, it sounds more attractive than carrying two parallel object models.

If you need to be able to recreate the application state at any point in time, then you're more or less stuck with writing them to a database (because of the fast random access). You could cheat and have a "history" table that has a composite key of id + timestamp + type, then a "json" field where you just marshal the thing down and save it. That would help with a) carrying one history table instead of a bunch of clone tables, and b) give you some flexibility if the schema changes (i.e. leverage the open schema nature of JSON)

But since it's archive data with a different usage pattern (you're just reading/writing the records whole), I'd think about some other means of storing it than with the same strict schema as the live data.

It's a nice application of the "write once" paradigm... do you have Hadoop available? ;)

Comment: I am very open to any solution. I do not have Hadoop, what would Hadoop bring me? I am building an historical db of financial data...

Comment: Oh, Hadoop is just a nice, big datastore to dump data into and not worry about it. But it's probably massive overkill here. But the nice thing is that it really opened my eyes to the "write once" paradigm... i.e. you write the data one time and never update it... only reads. Which is what your history data is. You can make all kinds of powerful simplifications if that's the case.